# Disabling iPhone Specific Controls in Web Browser

Tags: jquery, html, iphone

I want to know whether is there any way to hide (1) and (2) in my attached picture.

1. When you tap on a text field twice this "select", "copy", "replace", etc. pop-up comes up, is it possible to disable via HTML5/CSS3 on iPhone browser?
2. When a keyboard pops up, it contains the dark top part which contains "next", "previous", "done" buttons by default at the top of keyboard. Is it possible to disable via HTML5/CSS3 on iPhone browser?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @NeXXeuS The picture looks fine to me...

Comment: Have you checked out http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW1 on apple.com?

Comment: Yes Matijs, I looked at apple's official site for devs but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that using HTML+CSS. These things are OS specific elements, and you don't have any control over them.

Comment: That is bad, a simple flag would be helpful.

Comment: It would be a huge usability problem because people expect those options to work, and don't like websites to disable options they could normaly use.

Comment: I don't think it would be a usability problem, contrary it will be a good UI practice if I can get rid of bulky and not so useful stuff from the screen.