# iOS Safari Mobile disable previous & next for select input

Tags: html, ios, select, input, mobile-safari

I had found a similar question regarding this problem last Friday, but cant seem to find it again.  If someone could poke me in the right direction, that would be great.

Essentially I have multiple select menu's on a page.  The first populates on load, the second populates determining on the selection of the first.  Simple enough.

However, in iOS devices, when you tap on the select element, it launches the iOS scroller for you to make a selection.  If someone uses the native iOS `previous` or `next` buttons, the following `<select>` input will not collect the previous selection data.  You have to physically tap `done` then launch the next select menu for the populated results to be accurate.

There is a website called http://m.lemonfree.com which forces you to tap `done` rather than `prev/next`, and also prevents you from tapping off of the iOS select menu to close the selection prompt.  Essentially forcing the user to select `done`.

I would be very interested in finding out how they achieved this functionality.

Cheers!

Here's my code just in case:

```
<form method="post" action="list.php" class="striped-bg-inverted">
  <p>
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <select name="make" id="make" required="required">
        <option selected>Select a Make</option>
      <?php foreach ($usedMakes->MakeResult as $MakeResult) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $MakeResult->makeId; ?>"><?php echo $MakeResult->makeName; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <select name="model" id="model" required="required">
      <option value="" selected>Select a Model</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button name="submit" id="submit">&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$("#make").change(function() {
  var makeId = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "process.inc.php?makeId=" + makeId,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      var list = "";
      for (i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        var modelId = data[i].ModelResult.modelId;
        var modelName = data[i].ModelResult.modelName;
        list += "<option value=\"" + modelId + "\">" + modelName + "</option>";
      };
      var theSelect = $("#model");
      theSelect.find("option:gt(0)").remove();
      theSelect.append(list);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313782/iphone-web-form-disable-prev-next-autofill-done-bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920952/remove-previous-next-and-done-button-at-html-form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443470/disabling-iphone-specific-controls-in-web-browser

Comment: All of those are 'related' however I had seen a specific solution that used jQuery to force cooperation, which I cannot locate again.  I have also provided an example link for testing this functionality in a way that I would like to implement.  I don't care if it's not 'suggested' behavior. My boss wants it, so I need to do it.  Thanks for the reference links, though.

Comment: More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574663/ipad-form-disable-previous-next-buttons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472465/disabling-previous-and-next-buttons-in-mobile-safari

Comment: Still not the solution I had discovered before, all a bunch of `disabled` and read-only solutions that just don't apply.  Thanks for supplying more links though.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how they do it as well :(

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but this worked for me in iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18273356/400728

Comment: Check out my solution, made a module to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use html `tabindex="nubmer"` attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

To prevent next/previous on input or select use `tabindex="-1"`:

```
<input tabindex="-1" />
```

**UPD**: I've checked http://m.lemonfree.com/ scripts and does not find anything magical about this form, see code below, that's all they have (So just try to use `tabindex`):

```
$('#PostCode_text').click(function() {
    $('#PostCode_text').val('');
});

var searchForm = new LemonFree_SearchForm();

$('#Make_select').change(function() {
    searchForm.loadVastModels(this.value, '#Model_select');
});


$('#Search_form').submit(function() {
    if (Validate.isZipCode($('#PostCode_text').val())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Also you can use `tabindex` attribute for <a>, <area>, <button>, <input>, <object>, <select>, and <textarea> elements

Comment: Great tip!  I am no longer doing any iPhone focused mobile development, so I am unable to test your suggestion.  Hopefully someone can confirm so I can mark yours as the (only) accepted answer.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: Didn't work for me - wonder if it has to do with the iOS version. I'm currently on iOS 9.3.2. Any updated solutions for modern phones?

Comment: @am5255 sure, it was almost 4 years ago. No idea for new iOS

Answer (score 2):

I made a module to solve this particular problem. [Here is the GitHub repo](https://github.com/ChrisWren/touch-input-nav), and below is a gif of it in action.

[image]

Comment: Great work!  This is an old question, but I am sure many people can benefit from your plugin.  Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: here is a problem, when the form2 is a select tag, and after I scroll options, the prev & next can be working again.